# Does Superpowered SDK Recorder Bypass audio processing on Android OS?

Tags: android, superpowered

i am working with Superpowered SDK for Recording purpose and i am able to record it properly. now, thing is all about quality. getting hissing sound in recorded file. i thought it could be of Headphone issue, but its premium quality Headphone. can i have some suggestions to get good recorded quality with Superpowered Recorder on Android Platform?

Answer (score 0):

Did you record the audio coming from the microphone or something else?

Comment: The hissing comes from the microphone, more precisely, it's a noise of your phone's audio hardware.

Comment: understood, but does superpowered Recorder Bypass any audio processing stuff of Android Media Framework?

Comment: I guess you use the SuperpoweredRecorder with SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO. In this case you are talking to Android's audio stack on the lowest possible level in user space.

Comment: yes sir, ultimate SuperpoweredRecorder will use audio stack of Android only, so does it bypass any processing before passing recorded buffer to user space?

Comment: System-space processing can not be bypassed from user space. Whatever your phone is doing in system space with the microphone input, it will still do it.

Comment: Understood. so, what is magic behind low latency of Superpowered SDK? is it DSP algorithm or that can not be disclosed?